# TypeError when Using Function in .format()

Tags: python, python-3.x, string.format

I'm going through *Learn Python the Hard Way exercise 24* while converting all Old style formatting (%) they used in the book into my preferred New style (.format()).

As you can see in the code below, I can successfully unpack the tuple values returned by the function if I assign a variable "p". But when I use that return value directly, it throws a TypeError.

```
def secret_formula(started):
    jelly_beans = started * 500
    jars = jelly_beans / 1000
    crates = jars / 100
    return jelly_beans, jars, crates

start_point = 10000

#Old style
print("We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % secret_formula(start_point))

#New style that works
print("We'd have {p[0]:.0f} beans, {p[1]:.0f} jars, and {p[2]:.0f} crates.".format(p=secret_formula(start_point)))

#This doesn't work:
print("We'd have {0:.0f} beans, {1:.0f} jars, and {2:.0f} crates.".format(secret_formula(start_point)))
```

Throws error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "ex.py", line 16, in <module>
        print("We'd have {0:.0f} beans, {1:.0f} jars, and {2:.0f} crates.".format(secret_formula(start_point)))
    TypeError: unsupported format string passed to tuple.__format__
```

1. Can someone explain why using function in .format() directly does
   not work?
2. How does one convert it into f-string?

Comment: Guess: try unpacking the results `format(*secret_formula(start_point))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the return value of `secret_formula` to `format` positionally isn't any more direct than passing it by keyword. Either way, you are passing the return value as a single argument.

To access the elements of that argument when you pass it as the `p` keyword argument, you use `p[0]`, `p[1]`, and `p[2]`. Similarly, when passing the argument positionally, you would have to access the elements as `0[0]`, `0[1]`, and `0[2]`, specifying the position `0`. (This is specifically how `str.format` handles format placeholders, not normal Python indexing syntax):

```
print("We'd have {0[0]:.0f} beans, {0[1]:.0f} jars, and {0[2]:.0f} crates.".format(
      secret_formula(start_point)))
```

However, it would be simpler and more conventional to instead *unpack* the return value with `*`, passing the elements as separate arguments:

```
print("We'd have {0:.0f} beans, {1:.0f} jars, and {2:.0f} crates.".format(
      *secret_formula(start_point)))
```

Answer (score 6):

that's because you're passing a tuple of 3 values as the output of your function

To make this work, you need to unpack the tuple, with the `*`

```
print("We'd have {0:.0f} beans, {1:.0f} jars, and {2:.0f} crates.".format(*secret_formula(start_point)))
```

You can also do this with an object, where keys should match the function parameter names, like:

```
def func(param, variable):
  return None

args = {'param': 1, 'variable': 'string'}
func(*args)
```

Comment: I had no idea you could do this in python!

Comment: you can do this with tuples, but also with objects, where object keys will be the parameter names of the function